# hiding the progress-spinner from progress dialog, android

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a way to hide or stop the progress-spinner inside process Dialog at runtime?

I dont want to hide or dismiss the process dialog.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String     failingUrl) {
    //progressBar.setProgressStyle(some_style);
    progressBar.setMessage("Unable to connect");                                                  
    iferror=true;      
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```

[image]

Could'nt find a style that can do this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by *"hide or stop the spinner inside process Dialog at runtime"*? There are no Spinners inside a ProgressDialog...

Comment: Its not `Spinner`, Its **ProgressBar**

Comment: i mean the loader icon as in the image. the one displayed when ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER is used

Comment: @PareshMayani thnx for clearing.

Comment: what do you want to do with that give an alert dialog instead if what you want is to show error to user